# nivoslider conflicting with fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have recently installed the latest Nivo Slider to my website. [www.desireandpleasure.co.uk/shop](http://www.desireandpleasure.co.uk/shop) however, now my fancybox pop up warning does not display.

I'm assuming its conflicting javascript, i'm not sure where to start. Anyone got any ideas or had the same problem, as i've seen other issues, but nothing as specific as this.

Cheers.

Here is the fancybox code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
.style5 {color: #6600FF}
.style9 {color: #6600FF; font-size: 16px; }
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "fbe78afe-9290-4572-880f-7dfb2e0b0ec3"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var    image_loading      = '<?php echo $tmpl['img']['cart_loading']; ?>';
    var    image_width        = '<?php echo $tmpl['img']['cart_width']; ?>';
    var    image_height       = '<?php echo $tmpl['img']['cart_height']; ?>';
    var    text_cart_quantity = '<?php echo $tmpl['txt']['cart_qty']; ?>';
    var    text_cart_subtotal = '<?php echo $tmpl['txt']['cart_subtotal']; ?>';
    var    text_cart_empty    = '<?php echo $tmpl['txt']['cart_empty']; ?>';
    var    cart_text          = '<?php echo $tmpl['txt']['cart_text']; ?>';
    var    cart_link          = '<?php echo $tmpl['url']['cart']; ?>';
    var    session_id         = '<?php echo $tmpl['session_param']; ?>';
    var    fetch_url          = '<?php echo $tmpl['url']['cart_fetch']; ?>';

    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
      var nameEQ = name + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
              var c = ca[i];
              while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
              if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
      }
      return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
      createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= TMPL_JS ?>jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= TMPL_JS ?>animebox.js"></script>                                                                                          
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.desireandpleasure.co.uk/shop/templates/OS04A00404/az_template/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.desireandpleasure.co.uk/shop/templates/OS04A00404/az_template/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
  #fancy_outer { top: 50px!important; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a#popupcontroller").fancybox({
    'showCloseButton'    : false,
    'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,      
    'frameHeight'        : 480,
    'frameWidth'         : 705, 
    'overlayOpacity'     : 0.9,
    'overlayColor'       : '#101',    
    'autoDimensions'     : false,
    'centerOnScroll'     : false,
    'onComplete': function() { 
      jQuery("#fancy_outer").css({ 
       'top': '50px!important' 
       }); 
      }                      
  });

  var cookie = readCookie('over18');                

  if (cookie != 'true'){                        
    if (window.location.pathname == '/shop/' || window.location.pathname == '/shop/index.html'){
      jQuery("a#popupcontroller").click();  
    }                                       
  } 
  eraseCookie('over18');      
});

</script>
```

Here is my Nivo Code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="sliderfront.png" data-thumb="sliderfront.png" alt="" width="725px"/>
                <img src="image002.jpg" data-thumb="image002.jpg" alt="" width="725px"/></a>
                <img src="image003.jpg" data-thumb="image003.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" width="725px"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: How about some code, as this is a coding help website? :o

Comment: what error if any shows up in the javascript console in your browser?

Comment: Hi Guys, added my code above. Also this is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Comment: So i'm assuming thats this line:   jQuery("a#popupcontroller").fancybox({

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function when you will define nivoslider or fancybox. I think it's can help you.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a#popupcontroller").fancybox({
    'showCloseButton'    : false,
    'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,      
    'frameHeight'        : 480,
    'frameWidth'         : 705, 
    'overlayOpacity'     : 0.9,
    'overlayColor'       : '#101',    
    'autoDimensions'     : false,
    'centerOnScroll'     : false,
    'onComplete': function() { 
      jQuery("#fancy_outer").css({ 
       'top': '50px!important' 
       }); 
      }                      
  });
```

But be sure than you use use for jQuery in noConflict. In another cases you should use "$"

Comment: Given my code above, could you help me with what it should look like as i am unsure?